# XML parsing compilation error

Tags: c, xml, parsing, compilation, field

```
void parseTexto (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *key;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"text xml:space="preserve""))) {
            key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            printf("texto: %s\n", key);
            xmlFree(key);
        }
    cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

I have the function above written in C for parsing a XML document field designated by text xml:space="preserve", however i am not able to compile my program due to the following error.

```
parser.c: In function ‘parseTexto’:

parser.c:102:67: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘preserve’

      if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"text xml:space="preserve"")))
```

Is there another way to write the field knowing that it needs to be a string for the function xmlStrcmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a double-quote `"` inside a string, which is delimited by double-quotes. So you will need to escape the quotes in the string with backslashes:

```
if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"text xml:space=\"preserve\""))) {
```